# Python print formatting of binary number

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a binary number I need to print including the leading zeros. So far I do this with:

`print("CRC -> {:08b}".format(crc)`

But this crc could have different sizes. What I'd like to achieve is a print statement that instead of `:08b` would take individual length like

`crc_len = (len(hex(crc))-2)*4`

But how would my print then need to look, how can I do conditional formatting depending on `crc_len`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first prepare the format string (because it is just a string, after all) and then use it for formatting the CRC:

```
crc = 23534
format = "CRC -> {{:0{:d}b}}".format((len(hex(crc)) - 2)*4)
#'CRC -> {:016b}'
format.format(crc)
#'CRC -> 0101101111101110'
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the "same" approach with string concatenation like `format = "CRC -> {{:0"+str((len(hex(crc)) - 2)*4)+"b}}"` but that didn't work. Yours does!